# Will Change set delete post monthly refresh

Tags: change-set, sandbox-refresh

We have a scheduled monthly refresh which pulls the code from Production and push on all the Sandboxes. This way we have the latest code same as Production.

I have a deployed a change set on one of the sandboxes. Post refresh, will the already deployed change set be deleted or will it still reside as the inbound change set.

In addition to the above, is there any way to rename the already deployed change set. If yes, how?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change set will not be deleted automatically, however any components which have been updated via the refresh will contain the code/configuration which the refresh pushed out.

A deployed change set will still show in the list unless specifically deleted (or on a Sandbox the sandbox is refreshed). An inbound change set or an uploaded outbound change set cannot be renamed.

It is only possible to edit the details such as name on an outbound change set which has not been uploaded to another environment.

Change set documentation [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=changesets.htm&language=en_US&type=0)